# Enlarge "hover" area of an element with jQuery - the easiest way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

What's the easiest way to achieve hover events (in jQuery: `element.hover(IN, OUT)`) for an area of a specified size around a certain element?

Let's say I have the element X and want the events to trigger when the mouse approaches this element with a distance of 50px from all sides.

Element X is nested complicated in a table, etc. so I cannot use any parent. How could I solve this issue with the element alone or with some nested element?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post some of your code?  Without seeing your code, I can recommend you try increased padding or possibly a floating element absolutely positioned on top of your clickable element but with a width and height +100 of the clickable element.

Comment: @Scott Thank youf or the response. Would code really help? I was looking for a sort of universal solution.
However, the lines I'm working with are very dynamical, so they are created with jQuery entirely. For achieving what I need, I'm trying the following code:
`X.parent().append("<div class='itest' style='position: relative; z-index: 800; width: 500px; height 100px;'></div>");
    X.parent().find('.itest').hover(IN,OUT);`
This simply doesn't work though. the events are never triggered (not even inside).. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could dynamically insert an element inside each element you want to have an enlarged hover area.  Here's an example that inserts a `hoverZone` into each `child` element with a larger width and height plus absolute positioning which moves it up and to the left to cover the child element.

Adjust the width/height, plus the absolute offset of top/left to give the enlarged hover area that you desire.

```js
function hovered() {
  console.log("Child element hovered!");
}

$(".child").append("<div class='hoverZone'></div>")

$(".hoverZone").hover(hovered);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 20px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.hoverZone {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  left: -25px;
  top: -25px;
}
.hoverZone:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the really detailed example! :) In the meantime, i've got to something similar myself at some points but needed a while to recognize that the surrounding parent element had the css "overflow: hidden" (for other reasons). That sadly blocks all kind of hover events which overflow as well, making those approaches impossible. >< I'll have to restructure the parents, etc as well.

Answer (score 3):

You don't really need any script for the additional element, it could be done with a pseudo :

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBLJO?editors=011)

```
div {
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

div:before {
  content: '';
  width: calc(100% + 100px);
  height: calc(100% + 100px);
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: -50px;
}
```

```
$('div').hover(function() {

  $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
}, function() {

  $(this).css('background', 'blue');
});
```

Comment: Your way is neat as well, thank you! Especially thanks for using that "calc" - didn't even know CSS had something like that now. Can be useful.

Comment: Can be very handy indeed and support for it is quite good, only really lacking with IE8- and early Android.